# Convert Dataframe to series and viceversa / Delete columns from serie or dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'am trying to convert this dataframe into a series or the series to a dataframe (basicly one into an other) in order to be able to do operations with it, my second problem is wanting to delete the first column of the dataframe below (before of after converting doesn't really matter) or be able to delete a column from a series.

I searched for similar questions but they did not correspond to my issue.

Thanks in advance here are the dataframe and the series.

```
JOUR  FL_AB_PCOUP  FL_ABER_NEGA  FL_AB_PMAX  FL_AB_PSKVA  FL_TROU_PDC  \
    0 2018-07-09    -0.448787           0.0    1.498464    -0.197012     1.001577

       CDC_INCOMPLET_HORS_ABERRANTS  CDC_COMPLET_HORS_ABERRANTS  CDC_ABSENT  \
    0                     -0.729002                    -1.03586    1.032936

       CDC_ABERRANTS  PRM_X_PDC_ZERO  mean.msr.pdc  sd.msr.pdc  sum.msr.pdc  \
    0        1.49976       -0.497693     -1.243274   -1.111366     0.558516



FL_AB_PCOUP                     8.775974e-05
FL_ABER_NEGA                    0.000000e+00
FL_AB_PMAX                      1.865632e-03
FL_AB_PSKVA                     2.027215e-05
FL_TROU_PDC                     2.222952e-02
FL_AB_COMBI                     1.931156e-03
CDC_INCOMPLET_HORS_ABERRANTS    1.562195e-03
CDC_COMPLET_HORS_ABERRANTS      9.758743e-01
CDC_ABSENT                      2.063239e-02
CDC_ABERRANTS                   1.931156e-03
PRM_X_PDC_ZERO                  2.127753e+01
mean.msr.pdc                    1.125987e+03
sd.msr.pdc                      1.765955e+03
sum.msr.pdc                     3.310615e+08
n.resil                         3.884103e-04
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Setup**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4]})

print (df)
   B  C  D  E
0  4  7  1  5
1  5  8  3  3
2  4  9  5  6
3  5  4  7  9
4  5  2  1  2
5  4  3  0  4
```

Use for `DataFrame` to `Series` selecting, e.g. by position by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) or by name of index by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) :

```
#select some row, e.g. first
s = df.iloc[0]
print (s)
B    4
C    7
D    1
E    5
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

And for `Series` to `DataFrame` use [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) with transpose if necessary:

```
df = s.to_frame().T
print (df)
   B  C  D  E
0  4  7  1  5
```

Last for remove column from `DataFrame` use [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df = df.drop('B',axis=1)
print (df)
   C  D  E
0  7  1  5
```

And value from `Series` use [`Series.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop.html):

```
s = s.drop('C')
print (s)
B    4
D    1
E    5
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

you can delete your particular column by

```
df.drop(df.columns[i], axis=1)
```

to convert dataframe to series

```
 pd.Series(df)
```